# What can cause intermittent connectivity from my wireless/wired mouse?

Tags: usb, mouse, troubleshooting

I'm using a Logitech [G700](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-us/product/g700s-rechargeable-wireless-gaming-mouse) 'wireless' mouse connected to a gaming PC, which is giving me some problems; I'm not sure if it's one problem, or two separate problems manifesting through the same peripheral.

The mouse is designed to connect wirelessly using a [Unifying Receiver](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/promotions/6072), but it also has a detachable USB cable that is used for charging the mouse as well as connecting it to the PC.

**Problem 1** - this has been going on for a while. When the mouse is connected to the computer with the charging USB cable, its connectivity is intermittent. It will seemingly spontaneously disconnect, remain disconnected for several seconds - the exact time varies, but normally around ten seconds - then I will hear the "New hardware" bong, wait a few seconds, hear the bong *again*, wait a few seconds, then the mouse becomes available again. Sometimes this will happen once in an hour, sometimes several times within five minutes. As you can imagine, it's difficult to play in this state.

**Problem 2** - and this is the more recent one. I recently had the guts of my system moved into a new case my Microcenter, then I wiped the SSD and reinstalled a clean copy of Windows 7. Since this change, no Unifying Receiver will work properly on the system. I put a receiver directly into a USB port and launch the Unifying software. The software asks me to turn the device off, then on again:

[image]

I do so, and almost immediately after turning it on I get the message "**We were not able to pair your device in the time we expected**".

I downloaded some software that was supposed to reestablish connections between Unifying receivers and devices; I see this screen almost immediately:

[image: enter link description here]

This has worked with this hardware in the past; Until the recent rebuild, I had got around the problem by connecting the charging cable permanently to a standalone USB charger, to keep the mouse powered, and used a Logitech unifying receiver to connect the mouse to the PC wirelessly. This worked smoothly for over a year.

I don't seem to have similar problems with my USB-connected keyboard, just with the mouse. I have now tried other Logitech wireless devices connecting to the computer, and they all seem to be having the same problem.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting this pest??

Comment: Do you have any USB3 running around? Or WiFi dongle somewhere?

Comment: Not sure if there's anything using USB3; the keyboard may be, but it's the only other USB device I have connected. There's no WiFi dongle, the machine is connected to the web via ethernet cable.

Comment: USB keyboards do not use USB3. Which keyboard is working, wired or wireless?

Comment: Keyboard is wired and is working normally; mouse is able to switch between wired and wireless.

Comment: What do you mean that M570 trackball can switch between wired and wireless? Do you mean a cable extender to RF dongle?

Comment: It has a somewhat proprietary cable that runs from a USB socket to the mouse; it's designed to be used to charge the wireless mouse, and to function as a data cable so you can use the mouse while it charges. The wireless dongle is a separate device connected to a different USB socket on the PC.